# User-/Author-Profile with List of Friends

Tags: views, users

I have a simple view of articles and on the right side of the page I want to display the user profile of the **currently logged in user** (user picture, some custom info fields, etc.) I'm doing this with a user view, which is working just fine. But if I click on a specific article, I want to show the article node and on the right side the **user profile of the author** of this specific article.

1. How can I display the author's profil on the node page? Is there a way to do this over a view?
2. The user/author profile needs to show a friendlist of this user.  What is the best way to do this? I would like to integrate this within the user/author view, but can't find a way...

Comment: did u tried Author Pane module?

Comment: I looked into author pane but I'm looking for a solution that

 1) can be used for both the author user and the current user
 2) easy integration of custom user profile fields